# Why is my CSS not applying to my React components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Say I'm creating a React app and have some CSS for components. I've added the style-loader and css-loader to my webpack config here:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './client/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { 
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
          }
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  devtool:"#eval-source-map"
};
```

I have a simple CSS file just to test on one component:

```
.list-group-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: red;
    outline-width: medium;
}
```

In my app I'm applying the classname to a element in my component and importing my CSS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import selectContact from '../actions/action_select_contact'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import '../styles.css';

class ContactList extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.props.contacts.map((contact) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={contact.phone}
          onClick={() => this.props.selectContact(contact)}
          className='list-group-item'>{contact.firstName} {contact.lastName}</li>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className = 'list-group col-sm-4'>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contacts: state.contacts
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectContact: selectContact }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactList)
```

I'm also importing the CSS file in the same way in the ContactList component itself. The rest of the project is [here](https://github.com/int-a/contacts/tree/add-style). I would have expected to see an outline around my comtactsList but there is not. There is no CSS when I inspect the page. Why is this not getting applied?

Answer (score 10):

In a react project created with **create-react-app** or **npx create-react-app**, I also had the same issue.

I had imported **index.css** file in my **App Component** but my styles were not being applied properly to my React Components.

I even tried directly adding **index.css** file in my html file in the public folder and using link tag to link to my index.css file (which resides within src folder).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../src/index.css">
```

That also didn't work.

Finally, I read an article about 7 ways to apply CSS into React. One best way was to install **node-sass** into our project and use **index.scss** ( import './index.scss') into **App Component** instead of **index.css**.

And Hurray!!! My CSS worked fine, All the Media Queries started to work fine.

Below is the code snippet you can try.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import './index.scss';


// --- Data to work with ---
const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'The Rudest Book Ever',
    author: 'Shwetabh Gangwar',
    img: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Rift0ymZL._AC_UY218_.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'The Rudest Book Ever',
    author: 'Shwetabh Gangwar',
    img: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Rift0ymZL._AC_UY218_.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'The Rudest Book Ever',
    author: 'Shwetabh Gangwar',
    img: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Rift0ymZL._AC_UY218_.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'The Rudest Book Ever',
    author: 'Shwetabh Gangwar',
    img: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Rift0ymZL._AC_UY218_.jpg'
  },
];


const Book = ({ book }) => {
  return (
    <div className={"book"}>

      <img src={book.img} alt="book image" />

      <h3>{book.name}</h3>
      <p>{book.author}</p>
    </div>
  )
};

const Books = () => {
  return (
    <main className={"books"}>
      {
        books.map(book => {
          return (<Book book={book} key={book.id} />)
        })
      }
    </main>
  )
};


// Work a bit fast | one step at a time
const App = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h2>Books</h2>
      <Books />
    </main>
  )
}

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
/* --- Mobile First Design --- */
.books{
  text-align: center;
};

.book{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #001a6e; 
  color: #fff;
  margin:auto;
};

h2{
  text-align: center;
}

/* --- Adding Media Queries --- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
  .books,.persons{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

To install node-sass, simple do  `npm install node-sass --save`
Then rename all your **.css** files with **.scss** and your project with work properly.

The **package.json** should have the **node-sass** dependency added as shown below:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
```

Hope this will help many developers :)

Answer (score 5):

It would be helpful to see your React component as well.

Given this code, you are passing className as a property into the component rather than assigning a class to it:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        /** This line specifically **/
        <ContactList className="contactList" />
        <ContactDetail />
        <AddContactModal />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside your component, you would need to use `className={this.props.className}` on a regular HTML tag inside of your component in order to pass the className through.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your specific css file to index.js directly. (like this `import './master.css'`
)

Answer (score 0):

According to the react documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) the className can be applied to all DOM regular element such as `<div>`, `<a>`, ...

Does your CSS works with the regular tag `<div className='contactList'>hello</div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

### Styling React Using CSS

I had a problem with applying css file to my react component, which solved by adding a .module.css extension to my css file name. I found the answer [here in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33561647)

Answer (score 0):

Link to your CSS file inside index.js:

```js
import "../static/css/index.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy mistake that I ve done with the code is;

adding extra div at the beginning and thinking that this is the main conatiner div. Took my 2 days to realize what I done. gdmnt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).