# CSS Flexbox children items not taking up full available width

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

I'm trying to position the title of a card component to the left most side and some other data to the right most, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

the component I've written for this looks like the following:

```
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-title">Some Title</div>
      <div className="card-data">
        <span>{`Some data: 07/22/2020`}</span>
        <span>TEST</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For the CSS, I've seen from several previous posts that a solution is to assign `flex-grow:1` or `flex: 1 1 auto` to the children items. For that I've done the following:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .card-title {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .card-data {
     flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Despite specifying the `flex-grow` to be 1, it's not taking up the full space of the content, as highlighted here.

[image]

The `card` div is literally at the top of the component so nothing else is messing with the styles here. Is there any other property/specification needed here to make the two divs take up the full width?

Comment: try just this:
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

Comment: @dp.js not quite sure I understand the rationale behind this. the `flex: 1` property is supposed to be on the child item, right? I tried adding the `flex: 1` to the parent though, which didn't solve this, unfortunately.

Comment: You are right. No need of flex:1 to the parent card element. Just {display: flex, justify-content: space-between} should do. Possible to share a reproducible demo? Because clearly whatever you have tried is correct and works for a few of us

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make the `.card-title` and `.card-data` elements take up half of the card width, as well as being positioned to the left and right side, try this:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .card-title {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .card-data {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

Comment: getting the exact same output, sadly. I tried assigning background colors to verify that the selectors are not messed up and they're not. It's just not taking the flex-grow: 1 property at all, for some reason. Your solution makes sense to me, not sure why it's not working. If, for example I do something like a `margin-right: 700px` for example on the `card-title` card, that does push the `.card-data` content all the way to the right but hardcoding margin values like this is not something that helps me here.

Comment: Could you please try to inspect the `.card` element with the browser devtools and see if the element is as wide as the container? Or just add border to the `.card` and see if it wraps only the text or the whole row. I wonder if there is some issue with the elements' width.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `flex: 1` in card-title and card-data just use flex property on card.

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: this is the first thing that I've tried, not sure why but this didn't work.

Comment: try with `width: 100%` to `.card` element.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything wrong, should just work using what you wrote and applying `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1` to the children elements of the card. You got something else in your CSS/DOM that interferes.

https://jsfiddle.net/cg9y3mv6/

Comment: this is what I'm assuming as well and quite frankly this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of caching issue or that the css is not applying to your component for some reason? Someone had som similar issues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729132/why-is-my-css-not-applying-to-my-react-components

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to define class on element as **class attribute** not className. Than everything will work

```html
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title">Some Title</div>
      <div class="card-data">
        <span>{`Some data: 07/22/2020`}</span>
        <span>TEST</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```